# Is it possible to use .ctags file from anywhere else than home directory?

Tags: unix, ctags

Is there a way *ctags* can look for `.ctags` file other than home directory?

I have tried passing configuration like this `--options=<file path>`.

Even this was not working. This is expecting just file name, not full path.

My use case is that I need to make *ctags* pick my configuration file which is not in home directory.

```
$ ctags --version
```

> Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
>     Compiled: Jul  9 2009, 17:05:35
>     Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
>     Optional compiled features: +win32, +regex, +internal-sort

Answer (score 1):

[Section Files in Manual](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html#FILES) lists all directories where a system-wide *ctags* configuration file is searched for by *ctags* executable.

There can be also used on Unix:

- `/etc/ctags.conf`
- `/usr/local/etc/ctags.conf`

And of course `−−options=file` can be used to specify file containing one option per line which are additionally read and used. The file name can be specified with or without path. But depending on file name and path it might be necessary to use surrounding quotes.